# ASP.NET MVC Registering custom culture and internationalization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internationalization, cultureinfo

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 project and I've registered the custom culture in it because I want to have a client-specific translation.

I call the following helper method with parameters like `RegisterCulture("en-GB-CustA", "English (Customer A)", "en-GB");` This call is done in `Application_Start` event handler of the `MvcApplication : HttpApplication` class.

```
private static void RegisterCulture(string cultureCode, string cultureName, string baseCultureCode)
{
    var ci = new CultureInfo(baseCultureCode);
    var ri = new RegionInfo(ci.Name);
    var builder = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder(cultureCode, CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);
    builder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(ci);
    builder.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(ri);

    builder.CultureEnglishName = cultureName;
    builder.CultureNativeName = cultureName;

    try
    {
        builder.Register();
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {

    }
}
```

The method is fairy simple, it basically creates new culture based on existing one and replaces it's name.

Now in my Global.asax just for the testing purposes I've put the following code to `MvcApplication` class to switch current thread for the custom one.

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB-CustA");

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
}
```

I've also included two resources files. One is called `Test.resx` which is for the default texts, the second one is `Test.en-GB-CustA.resx`. I've added a simple string resource there called `Title` with two different values.

```
Test.resx => "Hello World!"
Test.en-GB-CustA => "Hello from custom culture!"
```

I've also put on one of my view the code to display this title (I've added `ViewRes` as s `CustomToolNamespace` for both resource files for simplification).

```
@ViewRes.Test.Title
```

Unfortunatelly even though I've set the custom culture as descibed before I'm getting the detault "Hello world" value all the time. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up renaming the code form my custom culture so something like `en-XX`. I've also have to define both `TwoLetterISOLanguageName` and `ThreeLetterISOLanguageName` and it registered properly.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds really simple, and this is an old-ish thread but have you tried rebooting?

Your code looks fine.

I had exactly the same problem, the new custom culture (locale) was being created correctly, but not being applied against the resource file of the correct name. Restarting was the only thing that applied the setting changes.

The only other thing to check, is that you are running with administrator privileges - as you need these to create a new locale.

See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx